# Images disappear with width:100% when trying to make images responsive

Tags: html, css, image

I am using position:absolute; and z-index.

I want a large background image which fades into new images. I am going to have a form over the top of that and then they both have to be able to scroll up. (I'm just using some text at the moment instead of the form).

I don't want the background image fixed - I want it to scroll up with whatever's on top of it.  That's why I haven't used any CSS background code because I can only find stuff which makes the background fixed.

The problem with what I've got is I can't make the images responsive.  As soon as I put the width:100%; code anywhere the images disappear.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

  setInterval(function() {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
      .next('img')
      .fadeIn()
      .end()
      .appendTo('.fadein');
  }, 4000);
});
```

```css
.fadein {
  position: absolute;
}

.fadein img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#bg {
  z-index: 1;
}

#fg {
  z-index: 9;
  position: relative;
}

.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg" class="fadein">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="images/1.jpg" />
  <img class="img-responsive" src="images/2.jpg" />
  <img class="img-responsive" src="images/4.jpg" />
  <img class="img-responsive" src="images/6.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="fg" class="container">
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>text to enable scrolling</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you proposed Tesseract because I can't SEE it in my browser. Your suggestion didn't get posted somehow.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep the absolute images inside the #bg div, you should make it relative.

.fadein {position: relative;} or #bg{position: relative;}

Comment: I tried that but 2 bad things happen: The images jump around when they fade into each other and, the other div which is meant to lie on top of the image div goes down below the images instead of overlaying them.